# install IIS Advanced Logging from commandline

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm trying to install IIS Advanced Logging via downloaded 64 bit msi, but noninteractively from the command line. Supposedly

```
AdvancedLogging64.msi /quiet
```

should do the trick, but it seems to be doing nothing. I suspect this is because it wants the user to accept the license. Is there a command line flag to force this through?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
AdvancedLogging64.msi /passive
```

Comment: no luck - it pops up a "preparing to install" window for a fraction of a second, but still doesn't complete the install.

Comment: @ElleryNewcomer strange... I tested it with success on 2012 R2 and can't imagine it would be different on 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

AdvancedLogging64.msi /qn

sometimes you have to be specific with the installers to have no gui

Comment: I've tried it. no luck. I've tried variations of /lx log.txt to try to get some diagnosis of what is happening, and the output is not useful. But if others can confirm that the above typically work, then it may be some idiosyncrasy of the particular box I'm using..

Comment: i tried running it on one of my windows 2008 SP2 boxes today and it worked completely silent only when i specified /qn  , what is the exact version of your machine and what is the effect your getting when attempting /qn is it the same as /quiet where you see nothing happen ?     i would try /q for a sec only to see if you get a prompt at all you might have an issue with MSI installation in general